# Identify a linear model with increasing then decreasing variance

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, modeling, model, generalized-additive-model

I try to modelise the following target variable from one of its covariable. I can't talk about what it represents. The color is the log1p of the number of points.

[image: target]

I tried a GAM model but the variance is not coherent with such models. This is the sd of the target :

[image: variance]

Do you know which kind of model I could use in this situation ?

Comment: Is this a time series?

Comment: I would rather see the plot that gave you the idea that variance increases and then decreases.  It might be that you can try variance function estimation.

Comment: It's a time series yes. I don't have access to the data for the next few days but I'll post other plots if needed soon.